Selling my Home
I am in the process of moving. My home was appraised last year for about 610K. I have a cash offer of 650K from a carpenter.
I have spoken to two realtors who want to list the home at 725K. However, I am concerned that they are giving me a higher number in order to get me to choose them to list my home. Is that likely? Also, they would be charging me about 4% (or maybe a bit more) for selling the home.
If I were to list the home at 725K and it took 6 months to sell, and it sold for 675K, that does not sound like a good deal. I am tempted to take the 650K now.
What should I do?

4% of $725k would bring you down to $696k (disregarding other costs). Have you countered the cash offer to be slightly higher, say $670k? That would bring the difference down.

Also, have you done any inspection related to the cash offer?

Did they explain in writing how the arrived at the value of $725K? did they list of nearby similar homes that were sold in the last few months?

Get another estimate from another agent, and make sure to ask them what they think it will sell for, not what they want to list it for.

@Nosjack I countered the  cash offer with 660K. The buyer responded with a no

@mhoran_psprep The agents had comps that defend their position However, the  comps did  not have  condition issues like I have.

@Nosjack I have not gotten any details on the cash offer. Maybe I should get him to put it in writing with the details.

Is the fact that the offer is from a carpenter relevant? Does the home need some work or upgrades?

@TTT The home needs work including at least one eew bathroom. This carpenters does bathrooms.

In your area, what percentage of homes are being sold for above and below the asking price? You know your home is worth at least $650k. Given the market in your area, is it possible that if you listed your house for 650, you would receive bids well above that? Just yesterday a realtor told me that he had listed a house for 350 and he was sure it would sell for 450. His said, "Buyers don't like to be told they have to pay a high price. They will offer more if the house has more value for them."

As @mhoran_psprep said, ask the realtors to show you a list of recent "comparables". That is normally how they estimate what a house might be able to sell for. Or you can look that up yourself on Zillow, but Zillow does tend to be overoptimistic.
As @nosjack pointed out, remember that agents will want a percentage of the sale price. Typical in the US used to be 8% on the total sale, split evenly between the seller's and buyer's agents, so this would cost you 4% of what the place sells for and cost the buyer the same. More recently commissions have dropped closer to 6%, so you might only need to take 3% off the sale price. Or if the market is hot enough you could consider going without an agent, but that may mean going without easy ways to advertise the place in listing services and definitely means giving up their experience and advice in managing negotiations.
As @Nosjack also pointed out, you don't have to take the first offer. This is a negotiation -- marketplace haggling -- and the buyer and seller have to find a price they are both happy with or find other people to sell to/buy from. You can certainly walk away from the offer. Or you can counter with "agents are telling me it should go for $725k; can we compromise on $700k?", and see what they come back with in turn, repeating the process until you either reach an agreement or fail to do so.
Even in a friendly direct-to-buyer transaction, you need your own lawyer. A lawyer is responsible for looking after their client's interests, and will try to write things to favor the client. The buyer undoubtedly has a lawyer, but you need an expert on your side to make sure that reasonable things happen or you can, and probably will, get scrod.*
I only know the buyer's side of this, so that's about the limit of my expertise.
[*Scrod: A young whitefish, commonly cod or haddock.]

Interesting, the 3 sales I've been involved with were always 6% commission total (although the current one was more negotiable). States: NM, CO, OR.

OK, I'll revise that; last time I was involved in the process was almost two decades ago.

Could also be regional. Mine were over the last 30 years, but the last two are recent (one still ongoing).

Definitely depends on the market. If housing stock is scarce and selling agents are competing for it, discounting their services is one way to try to make themselves more attractive... if they can still make enough profit at the reduced rather that the business is worth running.

In 2024 the way real estate pros are being paid is changing due to a court case. This could shift some of the burden onto the buyer. It is very confusing.

Why would not having a lawyer, as a seller, cause you to receive a fish?

@nobody: "I don't have that answer. Go fish." More seriously, isn't the pun obvious? I only included the definition because outside of New England, many people do not know that scrod is in fact an existing English word. Have we beaten this horse to death yet, or should I continue flogging? (If you have to explain a joke, it didn't work. Apologies for the failed attempt.)
